# export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am totally a beginner in React and while practising I ran into this issue. 
Through searching, I found out that 'withRouter' is not supported anymore by 'react-router-dom v6'. But I can't figure out how to change my code compatibly to v6. 
Does anyone know how to change this code instead of using 'withRouter'? 
 Thanks in advance!

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { readPost, unloadPost } from '../../modules/post';
    import PostViewer from '../../components/post/PostViewer';
    
    const PostViewerContainer = ({ match }) => {
      // 처음 마운트될 때 포스트 읽기 API요청
      const { postId } = match.params;
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const { post, error, loading } = useSelector(({ post, loading }) => ({
        post: post.post,
        error: post.error,
        loading: loading['post/READ_POST']
     }));
    
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(readPost(postId));
      // 언마운트될 때 리덕스에서 포스트 데이터 없애기
      return () => {
        dispatch(unloadPost());
      };
    }, [dispatch, postId]);
    
      return <PostViewer post={post} loading={loading} error={error} />;
    };
    
    export default withRouter(PostViewerContainer);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MC60.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, the `withRouter` Higher Order Component (HOC) was removed in `react-router-dom@6`.

Since `PostViewerContainer` is a function component, just use the React hooks directly. There's no need really for the `withRouter` HOC. In this case it's the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) hook you need to import and use.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'; // <-- import useParams hook
import { readPost, unloadPost } from '../../modules/post';
import PostViewer from '../../components/post/PostViewer';

const PostViewerContainer = () => { // <-- remove match prop
  // 처음 마운트될 때 포스트 읽기 API요청
  const { postId } = useParams(); // <-- call hook and destructure param

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { post, error, loading } = useSelector(({ post, loading }) => ({
    post: post.post,
    error: post.error,
    loading: loading['post/READ_POST']
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(readPost(postId));
    // 언마운트될 때 리덕스에서 포스트 데이터 없애기
    return () => {
      dispatch(unloadPost());
    };
  }, [dispatch, postId]);

  return <PostViewer post={post} loading={loading} error={error} />;
};
```

For reference, if you needed to still use an HOC for class based components you'd need to either convert them to function components or create a custom `withRouter` HOC.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();

  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      location={location}
      navigate={navigate}
      params={params}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

Comment: what's HOC? thanks

Comment: @YujinDong [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), defined in the first sentence. HOCs are an extension of higher order functions, i.e. functions that consume a function and return an *augmented* version of that function. HOCs consume React components and return an *augmented* React component, i.e. injected props, etc.